# How to display text in a TextView inside a Fragment

Tags: android, textview, fragment

Seems like a simple question to me, but I can't figure it out. I have this code inside my Fragment:

```
myTextView.setText("Test");
```

However, this code brakes my app and I am unsure why.  Perhaps this is a conflict with Views, but I still don't understand why it wont work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: how did you set the content?

Comment: Where did you declare your `myTextView` and where is the `myTextView.setText()` located?

Comment: Typically the Views aren't attached to anything until after `onCreateView()` completes and you don't need to search the entire Activity for your View if you know it's in the Fragment.

Comment: There are many simple things that could be wrong, post your `onCreateView()` method so we can see what you are trying to do. We'll sort out some of the confusion.

Comment: you said it breaks your app.. do you get any errors on your logcat?

Comment: Probably your myTextView object is null... You need to use it after onCreateView where you find your Textview on inflated view. Check for some sample of fragments ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you set the content?

Edited my answer :) try this

```
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xmlName,
        container, false);
    TextView tv= (TextView) **view**.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    tv.setText("yourText"); 
    return view;
  }
```

here is a tutorial for fragments : [fragments tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Comment: @DrewB Notice Elior uses `view.findViewById()` not `getActivity().findViewbyId()`, this is a critical difference.  Otherwise you really need to post the code that you're using and the LogCat errors, I can answer your question but I won't play guessing games.

Comment: Ha! We posted the same thoughts at the same time.

Comment: I don't know what is your Void method.. so sorry..if you don't post more code and tell us where the problem occurs ,  I can't help you more than that..