# Change TextView inside Fragment

Tags: android, textview, fragment

I followed this guy's [tutorial](http://arvid-g.de/12/android-4-actionbar-with-tabs-example) on how to make an ActionBar. Let's say I want to change the TextView inside one of the fragments. So I added this on my StartActivity.java, under onCreate:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textview.setText("HI!");
```

When I start my app, it crashes. Can somebody point me to the right direction?

I hope somebody takes the time to look at the guy's tutorial because his layout is basically the same as mine. Thank you.

Comment: what's the crash?? Show the logcat..

Comment: @Mnemone post the part of code which throws exception.

Comment: where u use this setText()...plz point out..in code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want change your component, I suggest you to make a method inside the fragment like this:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
            return view;
        }


        public void setText(String text){
            TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
            textView.setText(text);
        }

    }
```

Comment: getView() is always null

Comment: How do I access it from `MainActivity`

Answer (score 5):

Could you try to replace getView() with getActivity()?

```
public void setText(String text){
        TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        textView.setText(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Fragments_in_Android_-_A_Worked_Example), and on [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046149/how-to-display-text-in-a-textview-inside-a-fragment?rq=1)

It uses the inflater: (for me it worked)

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inf = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) inf.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText("New text");
        return inf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your main activity, instantiate your fragment class like this

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
          private YourFragmentClass your_fragment;

          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              your_fragment = new YourFragmentClass("pass the string value here")
    }
}
```

in your fragment class, you can then get the string and setText with it like this

```
    public class YourFragmentclass extends Fragment {

     private String your_text;


      public YourFragmentClass(String your_text) {
       this.your_text = your_text;
      }


      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

       //set the text of your text view
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
        textView.setText(your_text);
    }
}
```